# Using containers with typed actors give "incomplete type" errors

Tags: c++-actor-framework

When I add a container to a typed message I get "incomplete type" error messages.  Here is a simple example.  Notice how the final parameter in the "display_behavior" message is a string?  This actor compiles and runs great.

```
using DisplayActor = caf::typed_actor<
    caf::result<void>(display_behavior, time_point<system_clock>, string)>;

class DisplayState {
private:
    shared_ptr<Displayable> displayable_;

public:
    explicit DisplayState(std::shared_ptr<Displayable> displayable) :
        displayable_(displayable) {}

    DisplayActor::behavior_type make_behavior() {
        return {
            [this](display_behavior, time_point<system_clock> quackTime, string behavior) {
                displayable_->displayBehavior(quackTime, behavior);
            }
        };
    }
};

using DisplayImpl = DisplayActor::stateful_impl<DisplayState>;
```

Now I replace the string parameter with a vector:

```
using DisplayActor = caf::typed_actor<
    caf::result<void>(display_behavior, time_point<system_clock>, vector<string>)>;

class DisplayState {
private:
    shared_ptr<Displayable> displayable_;

public:
    explicit DisplayState(std::shared_ptr<Displayable> displayable) :
        displayable_(displayable) {}

    DisplayActor::behavior_type make_behavior() {
        return {
            [this](display_behavior, time_point<system_clock> quackTime, vector<string> behavior) {
                //displayable_->displayBehavior(quackTime, behavior);
            }
        };
    }
};

using DisplayImpl = DisplayActor::stateful_impl<DisplayState>;
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmm am I hitting an issue with serialization?  If I wrap the vector<string> in a class and then declare that class to be an [unsafe message](https://actor-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/TypeInspection.html#unsafe-message-types) then the program compiles and passes my tests.  I am still a bit confused though because [this page](https://actor-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/TypeInspection.html#data-model) shows how to write an inspect overload and the `point_3d` field has a vector member variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see this kind of error, it usually means you are using a type that has no type ID assigned to it.

Type IDs are used by CAF to generate meta data for messages. Based on this meta data, CAF can then implement "type switches" to automatically dispatch on message handlers based on the signature. As of 0.18.5, CAF assigns type IDs to some types of the standard library like the `std::string` (see https://github.com/actor-framework/actor-framework/blob/0.18.5/libcaf_core/caf/type_id.hpp#L375).

However, `std::vector<std::string>` has no type ID by default. This means your application needs to assign one. The boilerplate code for that would look somewhat like this:

```
CAF_BEGIN_TYPE_ID_BLOCK(my_types, first_custom_type_id)

  CAF_ADD_TYPE_ID(my_types, (std::vector<std::string>))

CAF_END_TYPE_ID_BLOCK(my_types)
```

And later on you need to also make sure to initialize the run-time type information. If you are using `CAF_MAIN` then it's just:

```
CAF_MAIN(caf::id_block::my_types)
```

If you are not using the macro, you need to add these lines *before* starting an `actor_system` (ideally first thing in `main`):

```
caf::init_global_meta_objects<caf::id_block::my_types>(); // custom types
// ... module types, e.g., caf::io::::init_global_meta_objects() ...
caf::core::init_global_meta_objects(); // default types
```

Currently (0.18.5), the manual discusses the type IDs under [Configuring Actor Applications](https://actor-framework.readthedocs.io/en/0.18.5/ConfiguringActorApplications.html). It's in this section mostly for historic reasons because adding the run-time type information used to go through the actor-system config. Maybe the type IDs should get their own section or at least move to the "Type Inspection" part of the manual.

> I am still a bit confused though because this page shows how to write an inspect overload and the point_3d field has a vector member variable.

You need a type ID for a type if you wish to send this type in a message on its own. This is required for the patter matching / type switch. Serializers can deal with `std::vector` and don't require type IDs. They operate on the `inspect` API. One fine day, C++ hopefully comes with (static) type reflection and most of the `inspect` overloads can be auto-generated by CAF.

Comment: Once again neverlord you have delivered a thorough and helpful answer.  I don't know what your role is in the caf project, but I hope you are happy to hear that my team has been so impressed by its capabilities.  The ability to spin up actors at runtime has enabled us to meet some challenging concurrency requirements.

Comment: I'm happy that CAF works well for you! I'm the creator/maintainer, so I'm always glad to see more users coming to the framework. :)

Comment: If you are interested, I would love to give you a tour of our architecture sometime.  We combined different examples from your articles and built a strongly-typed, supervised N:1 producer-consumer architecture.  The cool part is that each actor only depends on an interface.  This allows us to unit test most of our codebase without invoking any actors.  Furthermore with this approach we can isolate the N:1 actor system and exercise it using GoogleMock.  Like I said I would love to give you a tour sometime and hear feedback.  There might even be good content that we could generate around it.

Comment: Sounds awesome! Feel free to get in touch via PM, E-Mail or this contact form: https://www.cafcademy.com/contact-us. :)